# How to draw a pyramid

Tags: java

I want to draw a pyramid with the numbers from 1 up to the number entered by the user. I have currently tried

```
static Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
static ArrayList<Integer> by;

public static void main (String[] args){
    by=new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Enter Number : ");
    int no=s.nextInt();
    while (no > 9 || no==0){
        System.out.println("Value cannot be equal to 0 or greater than 9 \nEnter another number");
        no=s.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int a=1;a<=no;a++){
        if (a==1){}else{
        by.add(a-1);}
        Collections.sort(by);
        for (int o:by){
        System.out.print(o+" ");
        }
        System.out.print(a);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But I'm currently stuck at how to get the numbers to form the pyramid. I would appreciate any help. This is an example of a pyramid (I got using c#)

[image]

Comment: What should the pyramid look like, each level consisting of one number? If so, you'd first have to get the width of the maximum number and calculate the space between numbers accordingly.

Comment: Btw, `(a-1)==0` why not just `a == 1`?

Comment: @Thomas I added an example output of what I got in c# and thanks for the correction

Comment: Why are you overcomplicating thins using collections? Is it requirement?

Comment: @Pshemo Yes. Because I also modify the code and use it to perform another action

Comment: Looks remarkably similar to a coursework I had some years ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lest say that user chose 3 so your result looks like

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
```

while it should

```
  1
 1 2
1 2 3
```

So you need to move each row to right

```
__1   //move two characters to right
_1 2  //move one character to right
1 2 3 //dont move
```

General idea is to move line `no - a` characters to right. To do this just add

```
System.out.print(new String(new char[no - a]).replace('\0', ' '));
```

at start of your loop to print `no-a` spaces before each row.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before `for-each` loop

```
        for(int i=no-a;i>=0;--i){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen such a complex solution to this problem. You have used an arraylist, the Collections class and the for each loop as well. Here's a simpler solution if you are looking for one:

Assuming no is the entered number :

```
for(int i=1;i<=no;i++){
    for(int k=no;k>=i;k--){ System.out.print(' ');}
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){ System.out.print('%d '),j;}
    System.out.println();
}
```